# Listing role members in one single message - discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a command that lists the members of a role(it's called gangs on our server).

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def gangmembers(ctx,*args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    role_name = (' '.join(args))
    role_id = server.roles[0]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role_name == role.name:
            role_id = role
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not an existing gang, sorry about that.")
        return
    for member in server.members:
        if role_id in member.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
```

It does it's job correctly, but I wanna make it that it lists the role members on the same message, not 1 message for each role member. Is that possible to do? If so, what is the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them to a list, keep in mind that there is a character limit of `2000` in messages. you will get an error if you exceed it.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def gangmembers(ctx, *args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    role_name = (' '.join(args))
    role_id = server.roles[0]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role_name == role.name:
            role_id = role
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not an existing gang, sorry about that.")
        return
    data = []
    for member in server.members:
        if role_id in member.roles:           
            data.append(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
            
    await ctx.send('\n'.join(data))
```